# Не выводит текст из файла в консоль

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться , почему данный код не выводит текст из файла на экран

```html
Пушкин А.С. <<Евгений Онегин>>
Тургенев И.С. <<Отцы и дети>>
Логинов С.В <<Свет в окошке>>
Пушкин А.С <<Евгений Онегин>>
Стругацкий Б.Н., Стругацкий А.Н. <<Понедельник начинается в субботу>>
Янссон Т.С. <<Волшебная зима>>
Тургенев И.С <<Отцы и дети>>
Толстой Л.Н <<Война и мир>>
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

void sort(std::vector<std::string>& arr) {

}

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток вывода
    std::ifstream input("myproject.txt"); //открывается с помощью конструктора (поэтому освободится с помощью деструктора)

    if (!input.is_open()) {
        return -1;
    }
    //вектор стрингов
    /*std::vector<std::string> arr;
    {
        char str[1000];

        input.getline(str, 1000);
    }*/
    char c;
    while (!input.eof()) // пока файл не пуст, считываем из файла по одному символу и выводим на экран
    {
        input >> c;
        std::cout << c;
    }
    input.close();
    //str1 > str2

    //sort(arr);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ну если закрыть глаза на while с его eof (это антипаттерн в с/с++), то я вижу только одно причину - файл не открылся. или его нет. Хотя может он пуст

Comment: попробуй английский текст, если сработает, то придется парится с кодировкой